# Can it be possible to add comment with some other user's name in workitem of Azure DevOps using REST API?

Tags: azure-devops

The requirement is , the comment should be added from different ADO user using REST api and that should be calling from other 3rd party , for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhU2y.png) The Example is -
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you trying to call the rest api?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check my answer below? Hope the information could address your concerns. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The user who posts the comments is determined by the **token** generated by that user and used to authenticate in the request. In the hearer of the API request, PAT is used for basic auth and bearer token for OAuth.

If you want to comment in the name of another user, you need to know his/her token and use the token as authentication in the API requset, which is **not** recommended.